# Is Schatten p-norm a monotone ideal norm?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be bounded operators between Hilbert Spaces and define the Schatten p-norm 
 $(p \geq 1)$ \begin{equation*}
\sigma_p(T) = \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(T)^p \right)^{1/p},
\end{equation*}
where $a_n(T)$ are the singular values of $T$.

Suppose that $T \in \mathcal{K}(H_1,H_2)$, $S \in \mathcal{K}(H_1,H_3)$, and \begin{equation*}
||Tx|| \leq ||Sx|| \quad \text{for all} \ x \in H_1,
\end{equation*}
Does it follow that $ \sigma_p(T) \leq \sigma_p(S)$?

The case $p = 2$ it's clear, because the 2-Schatten class are the Hilbert-Schmidt operators and \begin{equation*}
\sigma_2(T)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||Te_n||^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||Se_n||^2 = \sigma_2(S)^2,
\end{equation*}
where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $H_1$.

What can we say if $p \neq 2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the $p$-Schatten norm is monotone. This can be seen from the following fact: A mapping $T:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ is of $p$-Schatten class if and only if$$\{||T\psi_j||_{H_2}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\in\ell^p$$
for all($2\leq p<\infty$) orthonormal bases/for some ($0<p<2$) orthonormal basis $\{\psi_j\}_j$ of $H_1$ and the $p$-Schatten norm is obtained by maximizing($2\leq p<\infty$) or minimizing($0<p<2$)the expression $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||T\psi_j||^p_{H_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ where the maximum or minimum is taken over all orthonormal bases
$\{\psi_j\}_j$ of $H_1$.
I proved this fact in my master thesis:

https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/analysis/download/diplomarbeit_melech.pdf

You find the proof in chapter 6 (p.36).
Since: $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||T\psi_j||^p_{H_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||S\psi_j||^p_{H_3}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ this proves the monotonicity of the $p$-Schatten norm for $0<p<\infty
$.

Comment: Ok, I found the proof of maximizing for $2 \leq p < \infty$. 
The case $ 0 < p < 2$ is equivalent?

Comment: Yes the minimum is obtained by the orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T^*T$ in this case

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||T\psi_j||^p=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(T\psi_j,T\psi_j)^{\frac{p}{2}}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(T^*T\psi_j,\psi_j)^{\frac{p}{2}}=\sigma_p(T)^p$ for this basis. This is actually sufficient for what You want to show. In both cases!!